# Do objects loaded from AssetBundle need to be unloaded after they are no longer in use?

Tags: unity, assets, asset-management, assetbundle

For example, in the `LocalizationProvider` class a `Sprite` is loaded this way

```
sprite = _assetBundle.LoadAsset<Sprite>(spritePath);
```

After the localization changed another sprite is loaded.
In this case does the previously loaded sprite need to be unloaded in some way?

While working with Resources I used to call

```
Resources.UnloadAsset(sprite.texture);
```

but I couldn't find anything similar for AssetBundle.

The same question about `Sprite` (or any other asset) loaded in the Editor with `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()`.